# Can a squatter exclude a subsequent trespasser from a property?

Tags: criminal-law, england-and-wales, trespassing, squatting

Meet Bob. Bob is occupying a property as a squatter and is awaiting his hearing date for the interim possession claim. In the meantime, he is organising private underground music events in the building. Suppose one of the attendees of the party is asked by Bob to leave, but they don't.

What options are available to Bob? Can he use reasonable force to lead them off the premises? Would the police remove them? That's actually all I can think of, but is there anything else?

Then suppose the unwelcome guest (who originally entered with a ticket and bobs consent) starts causing trouble, and threatening or assaulting people? Then Bob might call the police, and they would be invited into the property by Bob, or even if they didn't they'd be entering in with a lawful reason albeit even if without Bob's consent, either way thus clearing them of the criminal law act.

As they have not entered unlawfully, once they are inside, would they be allowed also to remove Bob using reasonable force, as he would still remain a (squatting) trespasser on the property?

Note that Bob has posted an entry opposition notice to the door informing would be entrants that it is squatted legally under s144 LASPO 2012 and that the occupants oppose their entry.

Suppose in version 1 that the owners have become involved in the way suggested by Peter. Then suppose in version 2 that they haven't gotten involved yet and made their opposition to Bob's occupation known.

Comment: How do the police know Bob's status?  And has the owner of the property reported Bob and/or served him with an eviction notice?  What sort of building is it - residential or non-residential? All of that will affect the response of the police.

Comment: Perhaps Bob posted signs on the door of the building advising them that it is squatted legally under s144 LASPO 2012 and that there are people inside at all times opposed to their entry.

Comment: Not sure if the owners have gotten involved, but suppose each case was true in separate instances.

Comment: You need to add those facts to your post as they are germane to the question.